# Not able to return string to main function?

Tags: c++, return

In the following code, I am finding what dinner I have to eat according to the diet plan. I pass diet, lunch and breakfast as inputs, and have to return dinner as output. Diet contains what I'm supposed to eat today. Each letter is some food. Breakfast and Lunch contain what I have eaten already.

If breakfast or lunch contain any element which is not present in diet, I should return "Cheater". Otherwise I have to find elements which are there in Diet but not in Breakfast and Lunch.

My code shows that Dinner has been successfully calculated. But It doesnt return Dinner.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class DietPlan
{
public:
    string chooseDinner( string diet, string breakfast, string lunch )
    {
        int lim1 = breakfast.length(), lim2 = lunch.length();
        int flag1 = 1, lim0 = diet.length();
        //Sort diet.
        for(int k = 1; k < lim0; k++)
            for(int x=0;x < lim0-k; x++)
                if( diet[x]>diet[x+1] )
                {
                    char temp = diet[x];
                    diet[x] = diet[x+1];
                    diet[x+1]=temp;
                }
        cout<<"Diet: "<<diet<<endl;
        //Sort breakfast.
        if(lim1>0)
        for(int k = 1; k < lim1; k++)
            for(int x=0;x < lim1-k; x++)
                if( breakfast[x]>breakfast[x+1] )
                {
                    char temp1 = breakfast[x];
                    breakfast[x] = breakfast[x+1];
                    breakfast[x+1]=temp1;
                }
        cout<<"Breakfast: "<<breakfast<<endl;
        //Sort lunch.
        if(lim2>0)
        for(int k = 1; k < lim2; k++)
            for(int x=0;x < lim2-k; x++)
                if( lunch[x]>lunch[x+1] )
                {
                    char temp2 = lunch[x];
                    lunch[x] = lunch[x+1];
                    lunch[x+1]=temp2;
                }
        cout<<"Lunch: "<<lunch<<endl;
        //compare breakfast and diet. as soon as there is a difference flag 0.

        for( int l = 0; l < lim1; l++ )
        {
            for(int m = 0; m<lim0; m++ )
                if( breakfast[l]!=diet[m] )
                    flag1 = 0;
                else
                {   
                    flag1 = 1;
                    cout<<diet[m];
                    diet[m] = '0'; cout<<" ho "<<endl;
                    break;
                }
            if( flag1 == 0 )
            {
                cout<<"Hicheater"<<endl;
                return "CHEATER";
            }
        }
        cout<<"Diet: "<<diet<<endl;
        //compare lunch and diet. as soon as there is a difference flag 0.

        for( int l = 0; l < lim2; l++ )
        {
            for(int m = 0; m<lim0; m++ )
                if( lunch[l]!=diet[m] )
                    flag1 = 0;
                else
                {   
                    flag1 = 1;
                    diet[m] = '0';
                    break;
                }
            if( flag1 == 0 )
                return "CHEATER";
        }
        cout<<"Diet: "<<diet<<endl;
        string dinner;
        int i = 0;
        // put the remaining characters from diet in dinner.
        for( int k = 0; k<lim0; k++ )
            if( diet[k]!='0' ) {
                cout<<diet[k];
                dinner[i] = diet[k];
                cout<<i<<" "<<dinner[i]<<endl;
                i++;
        }
        cout<<i<<endl;
        dinner[i]='\0';
        cout<<"Dinner: "<<dinner<<endl;
        return dinner;
    }
};

int main()
{
    string diet = "ABCD";
    string bf = "AB", lu = "C";
    DietPlan d;
    string din = d.chooseDinner(diet, bf, lu);
    cout<<"Dinner: "<<din<<endl;
}
```

Output:

```
    Diet: ABCD
    Breakfast: AB
    Lunch: C
    A ho 
    B ho 
    Diet: 00CD
    Diet: 000D
    D0 D
    1
    Dinner: 
    Dinner:
```

Dinner is not showing anything.
I would sincerely appreciate any help with this.

Comment: When dealing with strings you shouldn't be doing the `\0` stuff yourself.

Comment: When does string operation become so so so complicated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some misunderstand [string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) in C++.Maybe that you have mixed up it with the C style string.With `string` in C++, you do not need to set something like '\0', and we may not care how the library store it.When you declare a string, it's empty at first, so you should write `dinner += diet[k]` instead of  `dinner[i] = diet[k]`, the string will automatically enlarge itself.So lines of below should be modified,then it will work:

```
for( int k = 0; k<lim0; k++ )
    if( diet[k]!='0' )
    {
        cout<<diet[k];
        //dinner[i] = diet[k];
        dinner += diet[k];
        cout<<i<<" "<<dinner[i]<<endl;
        i++;
    }
cout<<i<<endl;
//dinner[i]='\0';
```

**More Tips**: Do not sort the string by hand, use the STL algorithm [sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you expected the string to automatically grow if you reference an element like `dinner[i]`. It doesn't. When you declare `dinner` it starts as an empty string. If your program then executes `dinner[i] = diet[k];`, it causes undefined behaviour.

To add a character at the end of a string, use the strings `push_back` member function.

Additionally, there is no need to add a '\0' at the end of a string.

Comment: @user2734637, it shouldn't. `dinner += diet[k]` should.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change

```
dinner[i] = diet[k];
```

to

```
dinner.push_back(diet[k]);
```

and get rid of the line with

```
dinner[i] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

you can declare dinner as : char dinner[100];

then at the main function getchar() and a return value of int to let the output stay in screen:

```
int main()
{
    string diet = "ABCD";
    string bf = "AB", lu = "C";
    DietPlan d;

    string din = d.chooseDinner(diet, bf, lu);

    cout<<"Dinner: "<<din<<endl;

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```